# Convertir datos de un Formulario html en formato JSON

Tags: php, html, json, post

espero que me puedan ayudar con esta duda. Tengo un formulario html y lo que se desea es que cuando el usuario da clic en el botón de Enviar se debe ejecutar una acción que permita que estos datos se conviertan en formato JSON. Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Código del formulario:

Formulario de contacto

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">

<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
```

```
<section class="form_wrap">

    <form action="" method= "post" class="form_contact">
        <h2>DATOS DE CONTACTO</h2>
        <div class="user_info">

            <label for="dni_number">Numero de identificación</label>
            <td><input type="text" id="dni_number" value="<?php echo $productDetails['data']['dni_number']; ?>"/></td>

            <label for="nombreyapellido">Nombre y Apellido</label>
            <td><input type="text" name="full_name" value="<?php echo $productDetails['data']['full_name']; ?>"/></td>

            <label for="contact_phone">Celular</label>
            <td><input type="tel" name="contact_phone" value="<?php echo $productDetails['data']['contact_phone']; ?>"/></td>

            <label for="email_address">Correo Electrónico</label>
            <td><input type="email"  name="email_address" value="<?php echo $productDetails['data']['email_address']; ?>"/></td>
        <br>                          

           <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="btnSend">               

        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Hola Liss Bienvenida a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas un poco acerca del funcionamiento. A veces es mejor anexar el código en la pregunta que colocar la imagen. Mencionas que te sirve que el envío se haga vía `AJAX`?

Comment: Tambien deberias agregar lo que intentaste con Ajax.

Comment: Bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Por favor para casos como este evita poner imágenes, ya que es de más ayuda el texto del código, el cual se puede copiar para hacer pruebas. La imagen sirve de poco en ese sentido y además se ve con dificultad en dispositivos pequeños. En cuanto al problema, ¿qué es lo que no funciona? El hecho de que falle no significa que tengas que renunciar a ello. Lo mejor para lo que quieres hacer es Ajax. El formulario se puede serializar y ser enviado al servidor. En el servidor debes buscar los datos de la forma correcta, claro está, de lo contrario no funcionará.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo editaré :)

Comment: Necesitas pasarlo a `JSON` pero no lo enviaras al servidor?

Comment: exacto, por ahora lo que necesito es convertir los datos de mi formulario en un formato JSON, estoy mirando estoy intentandolo con JSON .stringify () pero no me funciona :/  creo que estoy haciendolo de la manera incorrecta.

Comment: <script>
         function submitform() { 
            console.log('full_name');
        var obj = { 
            $name: $_POST["full_name"],
            $contact_phone: $_POST["contact_phone"],
            $email_address: $_POST["email_address"],
        };

        var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
        document.getElementById("form").innerHTML = myJSON;
        }

    </script>

Answer (score 2):

Con este código puedes serializar el contenido del formulario en un objeto JSON donde las claves tomarán el valor de `name` y los valores tomarán lo que haya en `value`.

Ten en cuenta que los elementos que no tengan etiqueta `name` no son serializados ni enviados con el formulario en caso de que éste se postee de una forma tradicional. He puesto una etiqueta `name` al dni, porque o la tenía.

#### jQuery

```js
$(function() { 
  $('#miForm').on('submit', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
  var jsonData=$(this).serializeArray()
    .reduce(function(a, z) { a[z.name] = z.value; return a; }, {});
    console.log(jsonData);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" class="form_contact" id="miForm">
  <h2>DATOS DE CONTACTO</h2>
  <div class="user_info">

    <label for="dni_number">Numero de identificación</label>
    <td><input type="text" name="dni" id="dni_number" value="1" /></td>

    <label for="nombreyapellido">Nombre y Apellido</label>
    <td><input type="text" name="full_name" value="Pedro Pérez" /></td>

    <label for="contact_phone">Celular</label>
    <td><input type="tel" name="contact_phone" value="633555555" /></td>

    <label for="email_address">Correo Electrónico</label>
    <td><input type="email" name="email_address" value="uncorreo@mail.com" /></td>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="btnSend">

  </div>
</form>
```

---

#### Javascript puro

Puedes hacerlo mediante `FormData` del siguiente modo.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {

  var miForm = document.getElementById('miForm');
  miForm.onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    var jsonData = {};
    for (var [k, v] of formData) {
      jsonData[k] = v;
    }
    console.log(jsonData);
  }

});
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="form_contact" id="miForm">
  <h2>DATOS DE CONTACTO</h2>
  <div class="user_info">

    <label for="dni_number">Numero de identificación</label>
    <td><input type="text" name="dni" id="dni_number" value="1" /></td>

    <label for="nombreyapellido">Nombre y Apellido</label>
    <td><input type="text" name="full_name" value="Pedro Pérez" /></td>

    <label for="contact_phone">Celular</label>
    <td><input type="tel" name="contact_phone" value="633555555" /></td>

    <label for="email_address">Correo Electrónico</label>
    <td><input type="email" name="email_address" value="uncorreo@mail.com" /></td>
    <br>

    <button type="submit" value="Enviar" id="btnSend">Enviar</button>

  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar el método que yo uso:

```
$("#btnSend").click(function () {

var parameters = {};
parameters.names = $("#names").val();
parameters.phone = $("#phone").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: "url/to/send/data",
            data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr);
                //alert(xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: Hola jamb1809, gracias por tu ayuda, no me funciono, sin embargo fue porque la pregunta no esta bien orientada, hace poco vine a entender lo que realmente necesito y voy a ir paso a paso con esto y para iniciar voy a preguntar como crear una acción en el botón. Es decir tengo mi formulario en html y cuando un usuario agregue los datos este convierta estos datos en un archivo json, creo que esto va en un script pero no se como es el proceso. Te agradezco mucho tu tiempo y ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Con Ajax intentaste algo como esto?

```
$("form" ).submit(function( event ) {

$.ajax({
type: "PUT",
url: "url/registro",
data: {
    nombre: document.getElementById('nombre').value,
    apellido: document.getElementById('apellido').value,
},
success: function (response) {

  console.log("exito")


},
error:function (err){
   console.log("error")
},
complete:function(){
    console.log("completo")

}
});

});
```

En data al poner lo que envías entre en este formato seria suficiente.
Entiendo que este es tu problema si no es por favor comunicamelo.

Comment: Hola Julian, gracias por tu ayuda, no me funciono, sin embargo fue porque la pregunta no esta bien orientada, hace poco vine a entender lo que realmente necesito y voy a ir paso a paso con esto y para iniciar voy a preguntar como crear una acción en el botón. Es decir tengo mi formulario en html y cuando un usuario agregue los datos este convierta estos datos en un archivo json, creo que esto va en un script pero no se como es el proceso. Te agradezco mucho tu tiempo y ayuda.